# PowerShell - How to locate an object(s) properties and methods? (They are not in the help files)

Tags: powershell

I have a few questions about the following code.

```
Get-DBAAgentJob -SqlInstance *instancename* | Where-Object { $_.HasSchedule -Match "False" }| Out-GridView
```

1. In the Where-Object, there is $*.HasSchedule.  What is '$*.HasSchedule'?  I looked in the help for Where-Object and online and I don't understand what that is. Is it a function?
2. What does this syntax signify/do  $_ ?
3. What all can I filter for in Where-Object other than .HasSchedule? Also,where I can find out how to figure that out please?  If it's not in help or books online or a google search, I'm not sure.  My google search algorithm is probably not good enough to get me in the ballpark.

I'm curious what are all the things I can filter on in the Where-Object in this line of code.  For example, instead of has schedule, if I wanted to look where the job is not enabled, is there a .NotEnabled?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: in addition to the Answer by Theo, one recommended way to gain knowledge of the structure of an object is to send it to `Get-Member` and to `Select-Object -Property *`. in your example, this >>> `Get-DBAAgentJob -SqlInstance *instancename* | Get-Member` <<< should show you the various properties and methods available on the object sent out by the `Get-DBAAgentJob -SqlInstance *instancename*` command.

Comment: Thanks @Lee_Dailey!  Is there a place to get the description of what the properties do, like a description in a help file, in case they are not self-explanatory?

Comment: usually, you can use `Get-Help Nifty-Cmdlet -Parameter ParameterName` to get details on any given parameter. you can also use an asterisk instead of the parameter name to get details on all the items. something like this >>> `Get-Help Get-Help -Parameter *` <<< will list the parameters and a short description. for more info, you usually need to go the the web page for that command and read up on the parameters there.

Comment: Thanks @Lee_Dailey, I'm sorry, I probably didn't explain well.   I was referring to descriptions of the properties, rather than the parameter.  So if I wanted to see what the property .hasSchedule means, or a description of it, properties are not in get-help from what I gather.  Is there such a thing as a description for properties anywhere, similar to what's in Get-Help for parameters?  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: arg! [*blush*] i misread your post. the online docs are usually the only way to find that info. you can sometimes find the source code for the command ... but even that rarely does into detail in a way that most folks can understand ... i know that i gave up on that method more than once.

Comment: No worries!  Thanks for all of your help!  It would be helpful if there was similar help for Get-Member properties and methods that's available with the parameters..

Comment: yes, the online docs are likely your best bet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Where-Object` clause is a way to filter objects returned from a cmdlet on a certain property.
In your example, it is filtering objects on the `HasSchedule` property. The example's filter says this property needs to be False in order for the objects to get piped through the pipeline where the next cmdlet takes them as input.

It tests the objects using the `$_` [Automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables), which represents each object in sequence that is coming in from the `Get-DbaAgentJob` cmdlet.

Usually, to find out what an object would look like, you can simply google for it.
In this case, if you look for `Get-DBAAgentJob`, you will find [this page](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/dbatools/0.9.18/Content/functions%5CGet-DbaAgentJob.ps1), where you can look at the function itself.
Here you can find what properties each returned object has:

`ComputerName`, `InstanceName`, `SqlInstance`, `Name`, `Category`, `OwnerLoginName`, `IsEnabled`, `LastRunDate`, `DateCreated`, `HasSchedule`, `OperatorToEmail`.

As you can see, there is a property `IsEnabled`, so you can filter on Not enabled with

```
Where-Object { -not $_.IsEnabled }
```

<sup>See: [PowerShell Logical Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_logical_operators)</sup>

If you click the home page for [dbatools](https://dbatools.io/) you'll fine a section called [docs](https://docs.dbatools.io/) where you can learn more.

Browse for free ebooks on PowerShell

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks @Theo, this is a great response.  I was looking for the properties in the normal help format, but in this case, it's located within the function creation code at the bottom.  Is this the typical way to find properties of functions, in the code that shows their creation?  That is, are functions not documented like cmdlets?

Comment: @JM1 It varies a lot. In this case we were lucky to find the function written out in full. Other times it takes more effort to get the documentation on a cmdlet you need. Sites like SO are also a great help in finding examples. Most times, seeking help within PowerShell gets you the info needed by using `Get-Help`. See [About Comment Based Help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comment_based_help)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone finds this useful in the future, @Theo's answer was helpful in giving me the base understanding of my question.

I learned more on this today and I will post it to help others in the future.

To answer my question:

- The .hasSchedule is one of the many properties of Get-DBAAgentJob.
- The . 'dot'.  "The most common way to get the values of the properties of an object is to use the dot method." Books Online (BOL)
- "All Properties and Methods for a given object are called *members*... Help files for any given command do not tell you what kinds of objects, properties, and methods are available, the only way to tell is to use the Get-Member' cmdlet.  Learning PowerShell Jonathan Hassall
- This code will tell you all of the properties and methods for a member, in this case the one I was interested in learning more about.

  ```
  Get-DBAAgentJob -SqlInstance instancename | get-member
  ```

This shows me all the properties and methods available, including hasSchedule and isenabled

[image]

BOL:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_properties?view=powershell-7